# Export products of particular category

Tags: magento-1.8, product, category

Is there a way to export products of a particular category in Magento?

If not, what are the tables involved if I want to do an custom SQL query?

Answer (score 2):

Here you can export all products from perticular category programatically. You need to create 1 file at root folder of magento files directory and create "catproexport.csv". And run the php file. So you can get the data in csv file "catproexport.csv". Also make sure you have write permission of that csv file.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app();


$categoryIds = array(2,4); // here you can write category id you want to export products from it.


$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('category_ids');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);//optional for only enabled products
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);//optional for products only visible in catalog and search
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$products->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds));



$fp = fopen('catproexports.csv', 'w');
$csvHeader = array("sku","name","category_ids","category_names");
fputcsv( $fp, $csvHeader,",");
foreach ($products as $product){
    $sku = $product->getSku();
    $proname = $product->getName();
    $catname = "";
    foreach ($product->getCategoryIds() as $id){
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id); 

        if($catname != '')
        {
            $catname = $catname . "," . $category->getName();
        }
        else
        {
            $catname = $category->getName();
        }
    }

    $categoryIds = implode('|', $product->getCategoryIds());//change the category separator if needed
    fputcsv($fp, array($sku,$proname, $categoryIds,$catname), ",");
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: does this code working

Comment: Yes , its working correctly.

Comment: Don't put the script in the root! If you want this script to be executable, place the code within the shell folder, so it's not available from the browser. And make sure you write the file to the var/export folder, so nobody can open that file from the browser. You don't want your data to be available online that way.

Comment: @ArjenMiedema , if we create file with name you created then other person not know the filename we created. so no worries. its for personal use. And nobody can know the filename we created. ;)

Comment: @ChiragRajput the name of the file is not the issue here. The issue here is that you don't want this to be available in any way from the outside world. It's a security thing. But in the end, it's up to you.

Comment: @ArjenMiedema , this is easiest and quick way to export as per my view. After use of file you can delete the files from root . And it not require ssh command which will some time dangerous for newbies. So as per my view this is simple and quick solution. Thanks for your view about this solution.  :)

Comment: @ChiragRajput giving newbies access to the root of your Magento installation seems pretty dangerous as well? Anyway, like I said it's up to you. If this works for you, you're question is answered.

Comment: @ArjenMiedema ,  newbies in the sense of who has no knowledge of ssh access and its command. Hope you will get my point of view. :)

Comment: @ChiragRajput Mostly it depends on the project's culture. If it's enterprise level with a number of developers it's not good to let them place stuff on the on the root as they might forget it there. 
If it's a personal project, a single developer (will create the export and delete it as you suggested) then that won't matter. Think about it like this, two actions one of them provides a certain percent of risk called X, and the other option provides Y risk, where Y is less than X, then why not taking the safest option.  This is especially important when there are juniors working under a senior.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "default" Magento way to do this. Normally, I'd do this using a shell script, where you can set the category ID as an argument. Here is the code I'm using for this (mostly changed based on the project):

```
<?php

require 'abstract.php';

class Armi_Shell_ExportCategoryProducts
    extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
    protected $_category;

    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
    protected $_products;

    /**
     * Run the shell script
     */
    public function run()
    {
        if (!$this->getArg('category_id')) {
            echo $this->usageHelp();
        }

        $this->writeCsv();
    }

    /**
     * Load the category based on the given argument "category_id"
     * 
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Category|Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
     */
    protected function getCategory()
    {
        if (!$this->_category) {
            $this->_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getArg('category_id'));
        }

        return $this->_category;
    }

    /**
     * Get all products for the given category
     * 
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection|Varien_Data_Collection_Db
     */
    protected function getCategoryProducts()
    {
        if (!$this->_products) {
            $this->_products = $this->getCategory()->getProductCollection();
        }

        return $this->_products;
    }

    /**
     * Create a CSV file in var/export, based on the category_id and the timestap, to make it unique
     */
    protected function writeCsv()
    {
        $fileName = Mage::getBaseDir('export') . DS . $this->getArg('category_id') . '-'  . time() . '.csv';
        $fp = fopen($fileName, 'w');

        /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection $products */
        $products = $this->getCategoryProducts();

        $headers = array_keys($products->getFirstItem()->getData());

        fputcsv($fp, $headers);

        /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $this->writeProductCsv($product, $fp);
        }

        fclose($fp);
    }

    /**
     * Write product data to the CSV file
     * 
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     * @param resource $fp
     */
    protected function writeProductCsv($product, $fp)
    {
        $data = $product->getData();
        fputcsv($fp, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Display the help for the script. For this one is hasn't been updated yet. 
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function usageHelp()
    {
        return parent::usageHelp();
    }
}

$script = new Armi_Shell_ExportCategoryProducts();
$script->run();
```

I have to say that it has been some time since I used it and this was a pretty basic version, so it might be that it needs some modifications.

Comment: If you don't mind my noob question. Where do I need to place that script? 
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You can add this script to the `shell` folder in your project. That's also the location of the file `abstract.php`, which is required.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Nevermind, I misunderstood the question. I went ahead and did a normal export from the admin and selected the needed category.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to export products filtering by category using the built in export tool or the Dataflow profile tool.

You can try to use a SQL query and then export the result to a csv, using flat tables you can do something like this:

```
select entity_id, sku from catalog_product_flat_1 cpf 
join catalog_category_product ccp on cpf.entity_id = ccp.product_id
where ccp.category_id = 2;
```

Or you can query for multiple categories like this:

```
select entity_id, sku, ccp.category_id from catalog_product_flat_1 cpf 
join catalog_category_product ccp on cpf.entity_id = ccp.product_id
where ccp.category_id in (2,3,4);
```